# What is the meaning of "countable spread"?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

I encountered an example that said:

> A Tychonoff 2-starcompact space of **countable spread** which is not $1\frac{1}{2}$-starcompact.

My question is this: What's the meaning of **"countable spread"** ?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105513/cardinality-of-a-discrete-subset).

Comment: There is a nice online reference: Apollo Hogan: [A Glossary of Definitions from General Topology](http://math.berkeley.edu/~apollo/topodefs.ps).
Some cardinal functions are also mentioned at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_function#Cardinal_functions_in_topology).
If you have a look at references given in the Wikipedia article, the books Juhász, István: [Cardinal functions in topology](http://oai.cwi.nl/oai/asset/13055/13055A.pdf) and Juhász, István: [Cardinal functions in topology - ten years later](http://oai.cwi.nl/oai/asset/12982/12982A.pdf) are devoted (cont...)

Comment: (...cont) exclusively to the cardinal functions and they are freely available online.
(Many books from the Mathematical Centre Tracts series can be found [here](http://repository.cwi.nl/).)
But you also find many facts about cardinal functions in standard references, such as Engelking's General Topology.

Comment: Thanks for the books link, Martin Sleziak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was answered in comments. Since we don't like [leaving questions unanswered](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1148/what-should-one-do-when-ones-question-has-been-answered-in-the-comments), I'll copy here the definitions from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_function#Cardinal_functions_in_topology).

The **cellularity** of a space $X$ is 
$${\rm c}(X)=\sup\{|{\mathcal U}|:{\mathcal U}\text{ is a family of mutually disjoint non-empty open subsets of }X \}+\aleph_0.$$

The **hereditary cellularity** (sometimes **spread**) is the least upper bound of cellularities of its subsets: 
$$s(X)={\rm hc}(X)=\sup\{ {\rm c} (Y) : Y\subseteq X \}$$
or 
$$s(X)=\sup\{|Y|:Y\subseteq X \text{ with the subspace topology is discrete}\}+\aleph_0.$$