# Intuition of countable sets using discrete sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, metric-spaces, cardinals

I'm trying to think of a way to intuitively explain myself what a countable set means.

So far as I understand it, in very simple words, a set $S$ is countable iff you can "name" or "list" down each and every member of $S$, so in a way, you've "counted" the elements of $S$ by "naming" them.

This intuition is directly inspired from the definition that $S$ is countable iff $S = \varnothing$ or $\exists$ a surjection $f : \mathbb{N} \to S$ so $f$ is a sequence in $S$ and thus you list down the members of $S$ as the sequence $\left(f(n) \right) = \left( f(1),f(2), \ldots, f(n), \ldots \right)$

Before, I go ahead. Let me know if this "way" of thinking about countable sets is correct or does it have any flaws?

Following that intuition, would it be correct to say that $S$ is countable if $S$ is a set of ***discrete*** points. What I mean by ***discrete*** is that there exists a neighborhood $N(s)$ around each members $s$ of $S$ such that $N(s) \cap \{s \} = \{s\}$.

Now, I know that "discreteness" is a topological property and it has nothing to with countablity, but hey, I'm trying to look for an intuition so think of $S$ (in this case) as some kind of metric space or something.

The only flaw, I see with the latter intuition is that if $(S,d)$ is a discrete metric space, i.e. $d(x,y)=1$ if $ x=y$ and $0$ otherwise, then any set $S$ now becomes countable, for e.g. if $S= \mathbb{R}$ but cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ is not the same as that of $\mathbb{N}$, so this intuition changes the cardinality itself. I mean cardinality is cardinality, the number of elements in a set shouldn't change no matter what, right? I feel like ***discreteness*** $\Rightarrow$ ***countability*** but converse doesn't hold maybe or something. So this intuition is lacking something, it would be very helpful if someone could complete or fix this intuition for me. Thanks!

**Any other kinds of intuitions are also very welcomed.**

Comment: Like you say it has nothing to do with topology, I am not sure there is much intuition beyond thinking of the natural numbers themselves.

Comment: I share your intuition about countable sets being a list. The discret stuff idea is not quite as accurate. For example the rationals form a countable metric space which is not discrete.

Comment: @copper.hat Yeah I know right, but I mean it'd be nice to think of countable as discrete sets, I know that intuition is lacking something. I'm hoping someone could fix that, if at all it is fixable.

Comment: Sure the natural numbers are discrete enough (unless they whisper to their neighbours)? It is hard to form intuition about infinities.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Yeah and that too :(

Comment: Natural numbers totally whisper to each other (and not just their neighbors!) and number theorist try to get a better understanding of that gossip since centuries :D

Comment: See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214863/are-finite-sets-discrete-by-definition/214879#214879).

Answer (score 1):

> Before, I go ahead. Let me know if this "way" of thinking about countable sets is correct or does it have any flaws?

Yes, this is correct. It's right there in the name: a set is countable if you can count it.

> Following that intuition, would it be correct to say that $S$ is countable if $S$ is a set of ***discrete*** points.

This is not quite right. The problem is that any set, arbitrarily large, can be equipped with the [discrete metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_space), or the discrete topology.

However, what is true is that if a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with the subspace topology is discrete, then it is at most countable, and this is a nice exercise. So, loosely speaking, uncountable discrete spaces are "too big to fit into Euclidean space."

> Any other kinds of intuitions are also very welcomed.

I wrote this in a comment but it's worth writing in the answer: a pretty good intuition is that a set is countable if its elements can be described using "a finite amount of data." In fact you can prove that the set of finite words on any finite alphabet (an "alphabet" is just a set and a "word" is a finite list of elements of that set) is countable, which is a very nice exercise and a pretty good way of making rigorous sense of the meaning of "a finite amount of data." For example the set of English sentences, or Python programs, or $\LaTeX$ formulas, is countable.

On the other hand, speaking somewhat informally, the real numbers are uncountable because to specify an arbitrary real number you need to specify infinitely many digits, which is "an infinite amount of data." Checks out!

The uncountability of $\mathbb{R}$ has the following somewhat disturbing implication: only countably many real numbers are describable by English sentences, Python programs, or $\LaTeX$ formulas. You can check out the Wikipedia articles on [computable numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number) and [definable numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definable_real_number) for more on this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but maybe you did not quite understand what I was trying to shoot for here. Let me be more clear. "It's right there in the name: a set is countable if you can count it." Yes **I know**. In fact, I've written exactly the same thing in the first half of my question. However, what I'm struggling to "explain myself" is that how would I know if I can actually count it. (I know, now you'd rightly say, "Hey just see if it satisfies the definition", cool but this question isn't about that.) (1/2)

Comment: @William: sorry, to be clear, the first sentence is meant to be me agreeing with what you wrote in the first half of your question. I can edit it to make that clearer.

Comment: Now for instance if someone were to ask me can you count the members of $\mathbb{Q}$, I (and I daresay anyone else) would have certainly said, "Hell no! Are you crazy?" because really where do you begin to count, where do you stop? And how do you even count? Hence I need a more stronger intuition of the word count. I know there are times one should just accept things with a pinch of salt but I just feel like I can explain it a little better if I try a little harder. I don't know if I'm making any sense to you :/ (2/2)

Comment: @William: there are several ways to say it. A reasonably clean way to say it is that you can count the elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ starting from the ones with the smallest numerators and denominators and going up from there. For example (sticking to positive rationals for simplicity) $1, \frac{1}{2}, 2, \frac{1}{3}, 3, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{3}{2}, \dots$. There are several different variations on this idea, which can be used to prove e.g. that $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is countable. Maybe "list" would be a better word than "count."

Comment: Basically every countability proof you'll ever need can be done using a combination of the following: 1) a subset of a countable set is at most countable, 2) a finite product of countable sets is countable, 3) a countable union of countable sets is countable. These are all good exercises. As a nice application you can try proving that the set of finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is countable. There's a down-to-Earth way to prove it using 3) and then a really slick way to prove it using prime factorization.

Comment: As for intuition, the finite-subsets-of-$\mathbb{N}$ result suggests the following intuition which is a pretty good one: a set is countable if its elements can be described using "a finite amount of data." For example this covers $\mathbb{Q}$ since the elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ can be described using finite strings of digits and the division symbol. In fact 2) and 3) above can be used to prove: the set of finite strings from a countable alphabet is countable. (In practice you'll only use this result for a finite alphabet.)