# Show that a discrete set is at most countable

Tags: general-topology

How to show that a discrete subset $A$ of $\mathbb C$ is at most countable? Ok I read the relevant questions here but I still don't understand how I should create an injection from $A$ to $\mathbb Q$.

If $a \in A$ then I can find a rational number $q(a)$ such that $D(a,q(a)) \cap A = $ {$a$}. But the map $a \mapsto q(a)$ is not necessarily injective because for example take {$1,2$}: it is discrete and I can for example take the rational number associated to each number to be $1/4$. So we don't necessarily have an injection unless something is done. Please explain in detail without hints how to construct this injection

thanks

Comment: See the answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105513/cardinality-of-a-discrete-subset). Clearly $\mathbb{C}$ is second countable, hence your set $A$ is too.

Comment: @DietrichBurde what you linked is some abstract algebra question

Comment: Oops, sorry. Corrected now.

Answer (score 6):

Since $\Bbb Q$ is countable, so is $\Bbb Q^4$, which means the set of all open rectangles with rational endpoints, $\{(a,b)\times(c,d)\mid a,b,c,d \in \Bbb Q\}$ is also countable. Such sets form a topological basis for $\Bbb R^2 \equiv \Bbb C$. Since $A$ is discrete, for each element $a$, there is a basis set containing $a$ that does not contain any other element of $A$. Therefore the cardinality of $A$ is less than or equal to the cardinality of $\{(a,b)\times(c,d)\mid a,b,c,d \in \Bbb Q\}$.

Answer (score 4):

Assume that $\phi:\>{\mathbb N}\to{\mathbb Q}^2$ is a counting of the points with rational coordinates in ${\mathbb R}^2$.

By assumption the set $A\subset{\mathbb R}^2$ is discrete. This means that for any point $p\in A$ there is a $$\delta(p):=\inf\bigl\{{\textstyle{1\over2}}|z-p|\>\bigm|\>z\in A, \ z\ne p\bigr\}>0\ .$$
It follows that $U_{\delta(p)}(p)$ contains  points $z$ with rational coordinates and among them one with smallest number $\phi^{-1}(z)$. In other words, we have a function
$$\psi:\quad A\to{\mathbb N},\qquad p\mapsto\min\bigl\{\phi^{-1}(z)\>|\>z\in {\mathbb Q}^2\cap U_{\delta(p)}(p)\bigr\}\ .$$
Since $U_{\delta(p)}(p)\cap U_{\delta(q)}(q)=\emptyset$ when $p\ne q$ it follows that $\psi$ is injective, hence bijective onto $\psi(A)\subset{\mathbb N}$. This proves that $A$ is countable.

Comment: With this construction, I think we can't assure that $\delta(p) > 0$. I meant, the infimum could be equal to zero..

Comment: @NicolasM.Gutierrez: For each individual $p\in A$ we have $\delta(p)>0$, because there is an $\epsilon_p>0$ such that $U_{\epsilon_p}$ contains no other points from $A$. – Of course the $\inf_p\delta(p)$ may be $=0$.